# If $\mbox{tr}(AA^*) < n^2$ then $|a_{ij}| < 1$ for some $i,j$

Tags: matrices, trace

> Let $A  = (a_{ij})$ be an $n \times n$ complex matrix and let $A^*$ denote the conjugate transpose of $A$. Which of the following statements are necessarily true?
>
> 1. If $\mbox{tr}(AA^*) \neq 0$ then $A$ is invertible.
> 2. If $\mbox{tr}(AA^*) < n^2$ then $|a_{ij}| < 1$ for some $i,j$
> 3. If $\mbox{tr}(AA^*) > n^2$ then $|a_{ij}| > 1$ for some $i,j$

---

**My attempt**

We know that

$$ \text{Tr}(AA^*)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2. $$

If $A$ is nilpotent matrix then $tr(AA^*) \neq 0$ but $detA = 0$. So option 1 is not true.

If $|a_{ij}| < 1$ for some $i,j$. Taking summation on both sides we get

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2 < n^2$$

I'm not sure that I'm on right path. Please help me.

Comment: Assume the there is no $(i,j)$ such that $|a_{i,j}|<1$ this implies that $|a_{ij}|\geq 1$ for $i,j$...

Comment: If $|a_{ij}|<1$ for *every* $i,j$, then we can conclude ${\rm Tr}(AA^*)< n^2$.

Comment: @Berci, please elaborate it if you enough knowledge about it. I think that your comment is right.

Comment: It is easier to deal with the contrapositives of 2 and 3, which are equivalent to them. The contrapositive of 2 is "if $|a_{ij}| \geq 1$ for all $i,j$ then $\mbox{tr}(AA^*) \geq n^2$", which trivially follows from your formula. Hence 2 is true. 3 is analogous with the inequalities reversed, and also true.